# Storing spawn stdout result as string variable in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to return the output of this function into a variable to be used in another function, but the variable returns as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```
function run(cmd){
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var command = spawn(cmd);
    var result = '';
      command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
         result += data.toString();
      });
      command.on('close', function(code) {
         return result;
      });
}
var message = run("ls");
sendMessage(user, message);
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Sorry updated my question. My problem is that the variable keeps returning as undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `run` function is asynchronous (because `spawn` is). The simplest method of passing its result would be to provide a callback function which is called when the results are in:

```
function run(cmd, cb) {
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var command = spawn(cmd);
  var result = '';
  command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    result += data.toString();
  });
  command.on('close', function(code) {
    cb(result);
  });
}
run("ls", function(message) {
  sendMessage(user, message);
});
```