# Node.js find blob on image using connected components

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am trying to x y coordinates of blobs in an image.

Following suggestions from this question:[Connected-component labeling with ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377463/connected-component-labeling-with-imagemagick)

I have this piece of code.

The end result correctly highlights the blobs.

However, I am unable to get the "verbose" output programmatically. I need the x y coordinates. AM I missing something?

```
gm('difference.png')
.out('-colorspace')
.out('gray')
.out('-threshold')
.out('90%')
.out('-define')
.out('connected-components:verbose=true')
.out('-connected-components')
.out('4')
.out('-auto-level')
.write("out.png", function(err){
        console.log(err);
        //how to get the verbose output about the blob positions??
    });`enter code here`
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't grasp Javascript at all, but maybe you can `spawn()` it like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15516475/2836621

Comment: Appreciate your offer to help. I found the way to get the verbose output for the blob positions...posted my answer...

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to get the output from the gm operations

```
gm(imagePath)
.out('-define')
.out('connected-components:verbose=true')
.out('-connected-components')
.out('4')
.out('-auto-level')
.write('out.png', function(err, stdout){
    //details in stdout
});
```

Comment: Well done and thank you for sharing your findings back with the SO comminity.