# How to check for corrupted jpg images using node.js and gm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick, stdout, graphicsmagick

I'd like to check for corrupted jpeg images and so far, straight in the command line I can use `identify image.jpg` which outputs:

```
image.jpg JPEG 1920x1200 1920x1200+0+0 8-bit sRGB 65.5KB 0.000u 0:00.009
identify: Premature end of JPEG file `image.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.
identify: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `image.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.
```

or
 `gm identify image.jpg` which outputs:

```
image.jpg JPEG 1920x1200+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 64.0Ki 0.000u 0:01
gm identify: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment (image.jpg).
    gm identify: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment (image.jpg).
```

It would be nice if I can use the [gm package](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) to get the corrupt JPEG data too. Simply using `identify()` outputs a lot of data, but nothing about corrupt data

```
gm('image.jpg')
.identify('%C',function (err, data) {
  if (!err) console.log(data)
  else console.error(err)
});
```

I've noticed this note in the readme:

> If gm does not supply you with a method you need or does not work as
>   you'd like, you can simply use gm().in() or gm().out() to set your own
>   arguments.

I've tried something like this:

```
gm()
.command("identify") 
.in('image.jpg');
```

but I get no output so I'm probably doing it wrong.

I've also tried node-cmd:

```
cmd.get(
        'gm identify image.jpg',
        function(data){
            console.log('output: ',data)
        }
    );
```

but I only see the first line of the output.

What's the clean/recommended way of getting the multiline output from `identify` via `gm` package ? Otherwise, what's a node elegant solution to reading the full output of the identify command.

**Update**
My guess is the string isn't displayed using `gm` because it comes through `stderr`, not `stdout`.

I've tested using a tweaked version of [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781214/parse-output-of-spawned-node-js-child-process-line-by-line):

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var bin = "identify"
var args = ['image.jpg'];
var cspr = spawn(bin, args);
cspr.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    data += '';
    console.log(data.replace("\n", "\nstderr: "));
});
cspr.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    process.exit(code);
});
```

What's the clean way of getting the `stderr` output via `gm` ?

Comment: Hi George, Sorry, I don't speak `node` but I think this is very similar - maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/a/43222531/2836621

Comment: If the problem is that you want to use `identify` rather than `convert`, you can make `convert` act like `identify` (and thereby use the latter's calling interface) by using `gm convert someImage.jpg info:-` optionally adding in `-verbose` if needed.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you very much for the input. I have adapted your suggestion to node:```gm(jpgPath)
.command('convert')
.write('out.png', function(err, stdout,stderr){
    console.log("stderr",stderr);
});``` and it works! If you add your comment as an answer I'd be more than happy to accept :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you. (Btw, I don't speak `node` either, I play by ear :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very unqualified to say anything much about **node** or **Javascript**, but the following idea may get you up and running.

As I understand it, you want to use `identify` but are unable to capture its `stderr`. We do know how to capture the `stderr` of `convert` though. So, the suggestion is to invoke `convert` in a way it mimics the functionality of `identify` but with the calling interface of `convert`.

You can do that like this:

```
gm convert someImage.jpg info:-
```

optionally adding in `-verbose` if needed.

That looks like this in `node` apparently!

```
gm(jpgPath)
  .command('convert')
  .write('out.png', function(err, stdout,stderr){   
     console.log("stderr",stderr);
});
```